# Drilled too deep into a thin wall, how can I fix that?

Tags: walls, drill

I'm very new to this & totally didn't take into consideration how thin the wall was. Now I have a hole running from one side to the other. How can I fix this from the other side?

I was mounting an IKEA Malm drawer to the wall for safety using the screws & tools in page 9 here https://www.ikea.com/de/de/assembly_instructions/malm-kommode-mit-schubladen__AA-2022892-5_pub.pdf

Comment: Assuming the damaged wall is Sheetrock. Pick up a small container of “light spackle”. A little goes a long way.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You'll have to provide some indication of what the wall is made of and _why_ you're drilling it. Please [edit] this info into your post, or this runs the risk of being closed for lack of detail. If, as @mreff555, suspected, you've drilled into drywall, most of the time, a hole does need to go all the way through it in order to mount things, so knowing _why_ you're drilling is important!

Comment: I was mounting an IKEA Malm drawer to the wall for safety https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/malm-kommode-mit-6-schubladen-weiss-60403584/ using the screws & tools in page 9 here https://www.ikea.com/de/de/assembly_instructions/malm-kommode-mit-schubladen__AA-2022892-5_pub.pdf

Comment: Are you saying that you were drilling through "this" side of the wall and that the drill bit poked out through the other side into a different room? If that's the case, then I wouldn't count on that particular portion of the wall being strong enough to keep your drawers particularly secure. Of course, that's a low, wide set of drawers, so the risk of tipping is pretty low to begin with.

Comment: @FreeMan yes that's what happened, the other side of the wall now has a small hole.I don't think the wall is a problem, because the weight of a child for example trying to pull the drawer will never be strong enough to cause any damage & that's the main reason I mounted it to the wall.

Answer (score 3):

Cut away any burs or rough edges around the unwanted hole. clean out any dust or loose particles.

fill with filler to a level below the surface of the wall (ie. indented) allow the filler to set hard.

Fill again below the surface of the wall, allow the filler to set hard.

fill again level with the surface allow the filler to set hard.

fill again slightly proud, allow to set hard,  sand until flat.

paint to match, 3 coats.

Answer (score 0):

Fill, sand and finish with paint as needed or paper.

Take care as it is all too easy to make more of a mess than you started with,.

Comment: That's a bit vague for someone who professes to being "very new to this".